# Have SSM start-session use bash

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I'm using AWS Simple Session Manager along with the AWS CLI to SSH into instances.  When I call `aws ssm start-session --target INSTANCE_ID`, it starts `sh` on the server, not `bash`.  Is there any way to customize the command that is run on instance start?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it using an AWS provided configuration document, like so:

`aws ssm start-session --target INSTANCE_ID --document-name AWS-StartInteractiveCommand --parameters command="bash -l"`

Source: [a github issue on the topic](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ssm-agent/issues/131#issuecomment-607026625)